# Startup time to run first unit test in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've traditionally used Eclipse/Java but am currently using Visual Studio 2015/C# and so I'm hoping I just have something misconfigured.  I am developing an ASP.NET core application and have a number of unit tests (~20) that I've created and am running using the xunit test runner.

When running with `dotnet test` the performance is what I would expect.  There is maybe a second or two delay while the application is compiled and then the tests are immediately launched (all tests run in less than a second once started).

However, when running via VS2015 using the test explorer window there is a ~30 second delay before the first test starts.  Once the tests start they run at about the same rate (<1 second for all tests) but that 30 second delay is significant and really interrupts my flow.  This delay occurs even if I select a single test to run (so it isn't test explorer's test discovery process).

Is there any way to configure VS2015 so that this delay can be avoided?

Comment: Did you check the output window? Most likely VS is building and discovering tests. Discovery runs even if you want to run only one test

Comment: Maybe using [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to see which file system activities are happening during these 30 seconds help to further nail down the issue?

Comment: I'll take a look at Process Monitor.  Is there any way to disable test discovery or avoid/shorten that time?

Comment: @UweKeim That was very interesting.  There was a large gap where the only thing happening were TCP reconnects to some server in my corporate network (perhaps an active directory server from the naming but I'm just guessing, it may be a proxy).  If I disable my network adapter then the startup delay is gone.  Any idea why VS2015 is reaching out to the internet when I start my tests?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @UweKeim I was able to track down the issue.  The VS2015 test runner was trying to connect to the local machine by the FQDN.  For whatever reason, the resolution of that domain name was taking a very long time  (some articles I found seemed to suggest it was trying to use NetBIOS for the name resolution).

Adding my FQDN to the hosts file fixed the startup time.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on your scenario here? What exactly do you mean by "Adding my FQDN to the hosts"? I'm running into something similar on my side and wondering if a similar fix would be adequate. If you could provide na example of what you actually did there (with fake machine names for example) that would be great.